# Conectar-se a Servidor Ubuntu com Putty+Xming

Tags: putty

Estou conectando meu servidor pelo Putty tentando usar o Xming para mostrar elementos GUI mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo. Sempre que tento executar um programa em linha de comando ele me retorna os erros.

OBS: a opção X11 no Putty está ativa

Firefox:

> Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

GEdit:

> Error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

Então eu fiquei pensando, é necessário que o sistema tenha interface gráfica para que o Xming funcione?

Comment: Qual é o comando que você esta usando para se conectar ?

Comment: estou conectando pelo putty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Então eu fiquei pensando, é necessário que o sistema tenha interface
>   gráfica para que o Xming funcione?

Sim, é necessário instalar os pacotes pertinentes. Por padrão, imagens de VPS não são instanciadas com eles.

Guia do Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

Pergunta em Ask Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/213678/how-to-install-x11-xorg

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo essa referência [xming+putty](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html), parece que você tem que marcar `Enable X11 Forwarding` e setar `X11 display location` com `localhost:0.0`, conforme figura.
Dessa forma, seu terminal ficará com as variáveis de ambientes corretas.

[image: imagem de configuração]

Se caso continuar com problemas para carregar os programas gráficos, pode tentar essa [resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209081/238899) do stackexchange. Que seria setar a variável de ambiente `DISPLAY=localhost:0`.

Comment: isso eu já fiz, infelizmente não funcionou :\